# hook_preprocess and theme_preprocess

Tags: theming, comments

I need to `preprocess_comment`.

I did :

```
theme_preprocess_comment($vars) {
 ...
 dsm($vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-edit']['href']);
}
```

But I need to do this in a custom module to override links depending about this module's configuration so I did :

```
mymodule_preprocess_comment($vars) {
 $vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-edit']['href'] = '/com';
}
```

Problem :

- `dsm()` returns `'/com'` but front is still

  - `<a href="/comment/26/edit"></a>` instead of `<a href="/com"></a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass by reference to modify the variable value:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_comment(&$vars) {
 $vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-edit']['href'] = '/com';
}
```

Note the `&` before `$vars`.

Comment: Woooooh, so obviously. How I can miss that... Thanks :)